# OpenGL doesn't draw my Quad. Everything seems to be fine. No errors from OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm trying to make a system that allows you to type in a position and scale and it will create a vector that automatically generates all the vertices. The problem is when I try to draw my object it just won't show up. I have used OpenGL's built-in debugging system but it didn't say anything was wrong. So then I tried to manually debug myself but everything seemed to draw just fine.

`Renderer::createQuad()` method:

```
Shape Renderer::createQuad(glm::vec2 position, glm::vec2 scale, Shader shader, Texture texture)
{
    float x = position.x;
    float y = position.y;
    float width = scale.x;
    float height = scale.y;

    std::vector<float> vertices =
    {
        x+width, y+height, 1.0f, 1.0f, // TR
        x+width, y-height, 1.0f, 0.0f, // BR
        x-width, y-height, 0.0f, 0.0f, // BL
        x-width, y+height, 0.0f, 1.0f  // TL
    };


    std::vector<uint32_t> indices =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    m_lenVertices = vertices.size();
    m_lenIndices = indices.size();


    // these Create methods should be fine as OpenGL does not give me any error
    // also I have another function that requires you to pass in the vertex data and indices that works just fine
    // I bind the thing I am creating
    createVAO(); 
    createVBO(vertices);
    createEBO(indices);
    createTexture(texture);
    createShader(shader.getVertexShader(), shader.getFragmentShader());

    Shape shape;

    glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_shader, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    shape.setShader(m_shader);
    shape.setVAO(m_VAO);
    shape.setTexture(m_texture);

    shape.setPosition(position);

    return shape;
}
```

`Renderer::draw()` method:

```
void Renderer::draw(Shape shape)
{
    if (!m_usingIndices)
    {
        // Unbinds any other shapes
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        shape.bindShader();
        shape.bindVAO();
        shape.bindTexture();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_lenVertices);
    }
    else
    {
        // Unbinds any other shapes
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        shape.bindShader();
        shape.bindVAO();
        shape.bindTexture();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_lenIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
}
```

Projection matrix:

```
glm::mat4 m_projectionMat = glm::ortho(-Window::getWidth(), Window::getWidth(), -Window::getHeight(), Window::getHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Creating then rendering the Quad:

```
// Creates the VBO, VAO, EBO, etc.
quad = renderer.createQuad(glm::vec2(500.0f, 500.0f), glm::vec2(200.0F, 200.0f), LoadFile::loadShader("Res/Shader/VertShader.glsl", "Res/Shader/FragShader.glsl"), LoadFile::loadTexture("Res/Textures/Lake.jpg"));


// In the main game loop we render the quad
quad.setCamera(camera); // Sets the View and Projection matrix for the quad
renderer.draw(quad);
```

Output:

[Output of the code before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYvCh.png)

Comment: Call `shape.setShader(m_shader);` before `glUniformMatrix4fv`. [`glUniform*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) sets the value of a uniform variable in the default uniform block of the currently installed program. Therefore you have to install the program (`glUseProgram`) before setting the uniform.

Comment: @Rabbid76 this is my fault. the `shape.setShader(m_shader)` copies the value of the m_shader (which is the ID of the actual shader) into shape so I can use it in the draw to call bind before I draw.

Comment: @Rabbid76 also my fault I call `glUseProgram` in my `createShader()` method.

Comment: Likely the geometry is clipped by the near plane. Try `glm::ortho( , , , , -100.0f, 100.0f`);

Comment: @Rabbid76 The fix you mentioned does not work, but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: We're just guessing here. You might want to read about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).